# Download with Python from URL gives No Host Supplied error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to make app that download comics but whenever I try to download an image, it says no host supplied.

I really searched and there was nothing.

This is the code:

```py
import requests,bs4
url='https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/71314/edge_of_spider-geddon_2018_1'
res=requests.get(url,stream=True)
res.raise_for_status()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
elem=soup.select('div[class="row-item-image"] img')#.viewer-cnt .row .col-xs-12 #ppp img')
#print(elem)
comicurl='https:'+elem[0].get('src')
res=requests.get(comicurl,stream=True,allow_redirects=True)
res.raise_for_status()
with open(comicurl[comicurl.rfind('/')+1:],'wb') as i:
    for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        i.write(chunk)
```

I expect it  to download the image but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\comicdownloader.py", line 10, in <module>
    res=requests.get(comicurl,stream=True,allow_redirects=True)
  File "C:\Users\Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 313, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\Islam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 390, in prepare_url
    raise InvalidURL("Invalid URL %r: No host supplied" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Invalid URL 'https:https://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/6/b0/5b6c5e4154f75/portrait_uncanny.jpg': No host supplied
```

And it gives it to me whenever I try it on any website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like `elem[0].get('src')` evaluates to `https://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/6/b0/5b6c5e4154f75/portrait_uncanny.jpg`.
so on line `comicurl='https:'+elem[0].get('src')` you add `http:` in front of an already well formed url, making it invalid

Comment: thank you very much i really want to accept your answer and leik answer but i dont know how and again thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Can't argue with this: `Invalid URL 'https:https://i.annihil.us/u/prod` -- the URL is really invalid, probably you should get rid of `https` in the following statement:

```
comicurl='https:'+elem[0].get('src')
```

Comment: It Works Man Thank You Very Much